# Lemmon slider previous button always sliding back to first page

Tags: jquery, lemmon-slider

I am trying to implement lemmon slider but it not seems working properly. When i am clicking on next it goes to next page but when i say previous then it goes to first image. but it should go to previous page images.

Below is my code. Can anyone tell me how to achieve it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/jquery/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/plugins/slider/lemmon-slider-0.2.js"></script>
<style>
#lemmon_carousel {
    height: 120px;
    background: #f7f9fa;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid #e1e8f5;
}
.lemmon_carousel {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lemmon_carousel ul {
    width: 20000em;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.lemmon_carousel li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.controls {
position: fixed;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="lemmon_carousel" id="lemmon_carousel">
<ul style="width: 2296px; padding-right: 680px;">
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/314472601_b16577aee0.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/1523115768_3709a167a2.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/2447082208_a8aaf7609f.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/2753126743_4249a4e948_b.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/3046575726_02f55b910e.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/3384297473_7a5f8e7933.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/4012245375_2e2b03d7b2_o.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/4117941853_3394b8bb27.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/CareBearsIRLbisousnours1550x283.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/Geof-Kern-Lego-580x434.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/OtLedSf.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/Raccoonholdingkitten.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/2447082208_a8aaf7609f.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/2753126743_4249a4e948_b.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/3046575726_02f55b910e.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/4117941853_3394b8bb27.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/CareBearsIRLbisousnours1550x283.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/OtLedSf.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/Raccoonholdingkitten.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/2447082208_a8aaf7609f.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/4117941853_3394b8bb27.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/CareBearsIRLbisousnours1550x283.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/Geof-Kern-Lego-580x434.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/images/x160/OtLedSf.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>    
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <a href="#" class="prev-page">Prev Page</a> |
    <a href="#" class="next-page">Next Page</a>
</div>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    $( '#lemmon_carousel' ).lemmonSlider({
    'slideToLast' : true,
    'loop':false,
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKKLS/1/) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Can you provide a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ? since you haven't wrote any custom code, it's probably an issue with the slider..?

Comment: Can you please copy -paste and run locally with your browser. I am facing issue with jsfiddle.

Comment: for running it in a fiddle, we'll need an online link to the plugin… Which will help everyone trying to troubleshoot your issue. If you can't find one, i'd suggest using another well known plugin..

Comment: Here next is also not working -- http://jsfiddle.net/UKKLS/

Comment: That's because of the syntax error, you're not closing the unload function. it's woking [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UKKLS/1/).

Comment: great added your link as jsfiddle